# Menu support for touch devices

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I've noticed that on touch devices like the iPad or Surface the menus in my WordPress site do not work. When using a mouse on a desktop, as soon as I move over a menu item, the submenu automatically expands. However, on touch devices this does not work.

If I've followed the code correctly, http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.js is setting up the menu items to use the mouseover and mouseout events which do not work in a touch based environment.

Is there a way to fix this using the theme or does WordPress itself need to be modified to fix this?

Comment: First, one needs to know the theme you are using. Second, most current theme menu dropdowns  will open on the hover event on a "tap".

Comment: I found this plugin with a little googling. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mobile-pack/ Hope this solved your problem.